# Display partialview based on a url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partialview in _Layout.cshtml that I only want to display for certain urls. 
My first thought was in my partial I would use a string as the model **@model String** .
In the actionmethod that is called I would return this 
**return PartialView("_MyPartial", new string{Request.FilePath});** 
In the partial I would have an if block wrapping my outer div that would check the model to see if the url it contained was the url that can display the partial.

I don't like this way because I would have to hardcode the url in if block check

```
@if( Model == "/Test/Home")
{
    <div>
       Just an example
    </div>

}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to use hard coded strings, even if you did the validation within your view like you initially intended.

You can use

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

to get your current url and

```
Url.Action("action", "controller")
```

to generate the inacceptable locations.

That said, I would keep your logic determining whether to show the partial view within your controller.

```
if(showPartialView)
   return PartialView("_MyPartial");
else
   return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: Thanks this is a lot cleaner and keep the responsibility in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding actions based on the request is the responsibility of the Controller. Since the controller chooses the view, why not have it choose the partial as well? Figure out what, if any, partial you want in your controller, and pass it to the view on your view model.